# Friend && Template

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'm actually trying to get one template class to be friend with another template class.
Something like that:

```
#include  <iostream>

template < typename T >
class  Test1 {

  private:
    static int  wantToBeFriend;
};

template < typename T >
int  Test1<T>::wantToBeFriend = 1;


template < typename T >
class  Test2 {

  friend class Test1<T>;

  public:
    void  run() {

      std::cout << Test1<T>::wantToBeFriend << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Test1<int> test1;
  Test2<int> test2;

  test2.run();
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm not able to do it, gcc say that `int Test1<T>::wantToBeFriend is private`.
Anyone know how achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Friends are declared at the *giver* of friendship; not the receiver.

Comment: Sorry... I think i'm working too much. I delete this one, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friendship does not work the way you are trying to make it work.  When you have

```
friend class Test1<T>;
```

That means that a `Test1<T>` can access the private members of `Test2<T>`.  It does not allow `Test2<T>` to access `Test1<T>`'s private members.  If it did there would be no point in having private members as you could just make yourself a friend of the class and access them.

If we switch it around like

```
template < typename T >
class  Test2;

template < typename T >
class  Test1 {
  friend class Test2<T>;

  private:
    static int  wantToBeFriend;
};
```

Then the code compile fine as now `Test2<T>` can access the private members([Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b0393c6622ad020)).

Comment: I was about to delete this one, but i'll accept your answer then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it the other way round. `Test1` needs to declare `Test2` as a friend class:

```
#include  <iostream>

template <typename T> class Test2;

template < typename T >
class  Test1 {
  template <typename U> friend class Test2; 
  private:
    static int  wantToBeFriend;
};

template < typename T >
int  Test1<T>::wantToBeFriend = 1;


template < typename T >
class  Test2 {

  public:
    void  run() {

      std::cout << Test1<T>::wantToBeFriend << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
//  Test1<int> test1;
  Test2<int> test2;

  test2.run();
  return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/034eac85188882fb)